# Multithreading vs Background jobs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have an application that makes thousands of requests to a web service API. Each request takes about 2 seconds, then the response creates new record in the database. I want to just fire off as many of those requests as I can simultaneously, and save the response to the database as as soon as I get the response.

Is this something I should be using a gem like sidekiq for, or the ruby `Thread` class? I don't want to just hand off the requests to be handled synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [thread pool](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/ruby-thread-pool) for performing the operation, and a database thread to commit the results.

You can build one of these really simply:

```
require 'thread'

db_queue = Queue.new

Thread.new do
  while (item = db_queue.pop)
    # ... Deal with item in queue
  end
end

# Example of supplying a job

db_queue.push(api_response)

# When finished
db_queue.push(nil)
```

Due to the Global Interpreter Lock in the standard Ruby runtime threads are only really useful for managing many lightly loaded threads. If you need something more heavy-duty, [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) might be what you're looking for.